# Loops introduced by ORM Reduces Performance drastically

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table as shown below. It has accounts of type Fixed and Savings. I need to update the status of all accounts of user 1. There are 10000 accounts for this user. Essentially the logic would be as shown in the following SQL Stored Procedure Script. The script takes only less than 1 second to execute (83 milli seconds).

But when I converted it to a ORM using **LINQ to SQL** it takes more than 3 minutes (204814 milli seconds).  It is at least **240,000%** slower.

Is there a pattern in LINQ to SQL (or other ORM) that will help to overcome this performance hit?

What can force it to do a  update in one go to database?

Note: I am aware of calling stored procedures from LINQ. I don’t see that as ORM and not an option for me.

[image]

**Manual Stored Procedure Script**

```
DECLARE @UserID INT 
DECLARE @StatusForFixed VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @StatusForSavings VARCHAR(50)

SET @UserID = 1
SET @StatusForFixed = 'FrozenFA11'
SET @StatusForSavings = 'FrozenSB22'

UPDATE BankAccount 
SET Status = 
        CASE 
            WHEN BankAccount.AccountType='Fixed' THEN @StatusForFixed
            WHEN BankAccount.AccountType='Savings' THEN @StatusForSavings
        END
 WHERE  AccountOwnerID=@UserID
```

**LINQ Generated Code Sample**

```
Note: This type of statements happen 10000 times

UPDATE [dbo].[BankAccount]
SET [Status] = @p3
WHERE [BankAccountID] = @p0
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [3585]
-- @p3: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [FrozenSB]
```

**CODE after applying ORM**

```
public class BankAccountAppService
{
    public RepositoryLayer.ILijosBankRepository AccountRepository { get; set; }

    public void FreezeAllAccountsForUser(int userId)
    {
        IEnumerable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> accounts = AccountRepository.GetAllAccountsForUser(userId);
        foreach (DBML_Project.BankAccount acc in accounts)
        {

            acc.Freeze();

        }
        AccountRepository.UpdateAccount();

    }

}

public class LijosSimpleBankRepository : ILijosBankRepository
{
    public System.Data.Linq.DataContext Context
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public List<DBML_Project.BankAccount> GetAllAccountsForUser(int userID)
    {
        IQueryable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> queryResultEntities = Context.GetTable<DBML_Project.BankAccount>().Where(p => p.AccountOwnerID == userID);
        return queryResultEntities.ToList();
    }

    public List<T> GetAllAccountsofType<T>() where T : DBML_Project.BankAccount
    {
        var query = from p in Context.GetTable<DBML_Project.BankAccount>().OfType<T>()
                    select p;

        List<T> typeList = query.ToList();
        return typeList;

    }

    public virtual void UpdateAccount()
    {
        Context.SubmitChanges();
    }

}

namespace DBML_Project
{

public  partial class BankAccount
{
    //Define the domain behaviors
    public virtual void Freeze()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}

public class FixedBankAccount : BankAccount
{

    public override void Freeze()
    {
        this.Status = "FrozenFA";
    }
}

public class SavingsBankAccount : BankAccount
{

    public override void Freeze()
    {
        this.Status = "FrozenSB";
    }
}  
}
```

**REFERENCE**

1. [Pass List as XElement to be used as XML Datatype parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324317/pass-list-as-xelement-to-be-used-as-xml-datatype-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing two wildly different scenarios:

1: running a script locally on the SQL server, a single set-based `UPDATE`

2: fetching 10,000 records over the network, updating each, submitting each individually

You can improve 2 a *bit* by deferring the `SubmitChanges()` into one single batch of 10,000 rather than 10,000 batches of 1 (just: don't call `SubmitChanges()` until the end), but that **still** involves sending the details of 10,000 records in two directions, plus all the overheads (for example, `SubmitChanges()` might *still* choose to do that via 10,000 individual calls).

Basically, object-based tools are not intended for bulk updates against records. If the SP works, use the SP. Maybe *call* the SP via a data-context, just for convenience of it adding the method/parameters/etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why you say "SubmitChanges() might still choose to do that via 10,000 individual calls". What are the governing factors for that? What can force it to do a bulk update?

Comment: @Lijo simplicity? needing to verify each separately, in terms of concurrency etc (not an issue in the direct TSQL approach). Some ORMs batch; some don't.

Comment: Do you think, the following approach can be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306344/loops-introduced-by-orm-reduces-performance-drastically/11331404#11331404

Answer (score 1):

You can still execute your stored procedure / custom SQL script from your application. You can even map the procedure in your Linq-to-sql model so that you don't need to open connection and create command manually.

I'm not exactly sure if Linq-to-sql always executes each modification command in separate roundtrip to database but I guess it does (at least in most cases). EF does it always. NHibernate has better support for such operations because it has command batching.

What you showed here is not batch update (single command updating a lot of records) - most ORMs will always update each record separately - that is how these tools work. If you load records and modify each of them in loop the relation to original query used to load records is lost. You now have 10.000 loaded records in your application which must be updated. The bulk update is not possible because you must move 10.000 changes from your application to the database.

If you want to do bulk update you should either use direct SQL or implement some logic which will make the update from Linq-to-sql instead of loading records and updating them in the application. Check [this article](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx) or simply search for Bulk / Batch updates in Linq-to-sql.

Comment: Do you think, the following approach can be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306344/loops-introduced-by-orm-reduces-performance-drastically/11331404#11331404

Answer (score 0):

This is because Linq to SQL First loads the data from server and then update each record individually which includes data query/transfer to client, update request for each record. Whereas  in SP case there is just a call to SP which executes the Update query on the server directly and it does not include data fetch and update of each record. It updates the record in bulk

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I did is passing the object values to the stored procedure as XML datatype. But there comes a timeout exception (after some 25 seconds) when the record count is more than 1000. Is it due to huge xml file?

Note: It takes around  5 seconds for 1000 records

```
   public virtual void UpdateBankAccountUsingParseXML_SP(System.Xml.Linq.XElement inputXML)
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LibraryReservationSystem;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=600";
        var myDataContext = new DBML_Project.MyDataClassesDataContext(connectionstring);
        myDataContext.ParseXML(inputXML);

    }

    public void FreezeAllAccountsForUser(int userId)
    {
        List<DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus> bankAccountDTOList = new List<DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus>(); 

        IEnumerable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> accounts = AccountRepository.GetAllAccountsForUser(userId);
        foreach (DBML_Project.BankAccount acc in accounts)
        {
            string typeResult = Convert.ToString(acc.GetType());
            string baseValue = Convert.ToString(typeof(DBML_Project.BankAccount));

            if (String.Equals(typeResult, baseValue))
            {
                throw new Exception("Not correct derived type");
            }

            acc.Freeze();

            DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus presentAccount = new DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus();
            presentAccount.BankAccountID = acc.BankAccountID;
            presentAccount.Status = acc.Status;
            bankAccountDTOList.Add(presentAccount);

        }



        IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> el = bankAccountDTOList.Select(x =>
                        new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("BankAccountDTOForStatus",
                          new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("BankAccountID", x.BankAccountID),
                          new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("Status", x.Status)
                        ));

        System.Xml.Linq.XElement root = new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("root", el);


        AccountRepository.UpdateBankAccountUsingParseXML_SP(root);
        //AccountRepository.Update();

    }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParseXML] (@InputXML xml)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (RowNumber int, BankAccountID int, StatusVal varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @MyTable(RowNumber, BankAccountID,StatusVal)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.value('BankAccountID[1]','int') ASC) AS Row,
    c.value('BankAccountID[1]','int'),
    c.value('Status[1]','varchar(32)')
FROM
    @inputXML.nodes('//BankAccountDTOForStatus') T(c);


DECLARE @Count INT
SET @Count = 0

DECLARE @NumberOfRows INT
SELECT @NumberOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM @MyTable


WHILE @Count < @NumberOfRows
BEGIN



      SET @Count = @Count + 1

     DECLARE @BankAccID INT
     DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(MAX)

     SELECT @BankAccID = BankAccountID 
     FROM @MyTable
     WHERE RowNumber = @Count

     SELECT @Status = StatusVal 
     FROM @MyTable
     WHERE RowNumber = @Count


     UPDATE BankAccount 
     SET Status= @Status
     WHERE BankAccountID = @BankAccID

END


END


GO
```

Comment: Changing from TDS to XML is likely going to *increase* the bandwidth... But could reduce the round-trips. Complex. Measure it and see.

Comment: Comparing time, XML seems to be marginally faster. But the challenge is with timeout exception. Is that behavior expected ? It takes around  5 seconds for 1000 records.

Comment: frankly I have no idea why you are changing something from "works well, quickly" to "barely works, slowly"

Comment: you have an existing SP that takes 1 second. Why are you moving away from that?

Comment: @MarcGravell I was trying to take way the business logic from existing stored procedure. Do you think that attempt is worth?